# initialize workmanager in flutter for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-workmanager

i'm trying to set up ios configration as document
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/main/IOS_SETUP.md
what's the wrong with this set up
i have this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(bgTaskSchedulingFailed(Error 
Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)") error, Scheduling the task using 
BGTaskScheduler has failed.

This may be due to too many tasks being scheduled but not run.

See the error details: Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"., null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:647:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Workmanager.registerOneOffTask (package:workmanager/src/workmanager.dart:187:7)
```

and this is my code
in main
//how local notificaion function
void callbackDispatcher() async {
final now = DateTime.now();
Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (prefs.getString('randomTime') != null) {
final checkouttime = DateTime.parse(prefs.getString('randomTime')!);
if (checkouttime.isBefore(now)) {
NotificationApi.showNotification(
body: "من فضلك قم بتاكيد تسجيلك",
title: "My App",
id: 1,
payload: "payload",
);
}
}
return Future.value(true);
});
}

```
 void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   NotificationApi.init();
   await GetStorage.init();
   final now = DateTime.now();
   prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   //initialize workmanager
   await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: false);
   //start workmanager
   await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
           "1",
           "simpleTask",
     );
  }
```

so i'm trying to show a local notification if time of somethin is coming

it work fine with Android

and this is my set up for ios files

in info.plist

```
       <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
       <array>
       <string>processing</string>
       </array>
       <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
       <array>
       <string>simpleTask</string>
       </array>
```

and this is AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
   override func application( 
   _ application: UIApplication,
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
   ) -> Bool {
     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self) 
     WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "simpleTask")
     return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
   }
  }
```

and this is project.pbxproj

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
   SystemCapabilities = {
     com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
     enabled = 1;
     };
   };
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First parameter of `registerOneOffTask()` in dart function must be same of `withIdentifier`  in swift, so in your case you need to change:

```
 await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
           "1",
           "simpleTask",
     );
```

To:

```
 await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
           "simpleTask", // <<<< change this
           "simpleTask",
     );
```

> Note 1: You need to use string with bundle name instead of `simpleTask`, so
> change it to something like : `com.example.project_name.simpleTask`

> Note 2: Workmanager plugin has a current problem with work on IOS
> devices, you can see many opened issues here [396](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/396) , [402](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/402) , [403](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/403) .

Comment: Hello mr.Anas I'm stack in this too, I tried ur solutions but with no luck, can you please explain  how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens only in simulator. It will work on real device.