# Flutter Workmanager IOS oneofftask not working

Tags: ios, flutter, background-process, flutter-workmanager

I'm trying to run a one-off task using the work manager plugin. Works fine on android, but on IOS I'm running into some issues.

I have set up as per the documentation here https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/main/IOS_SETUP.md. The only part of this I'm unclear on is in my info.plist and app delegate I have to register the task. I have seen on some SO and GitHub threads [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72788074/initialize-workmanager-in-flutter-for-ios) that I should be including my bundle ID before the task name. Should I be doing this in one, both or neither of these places.

I am running on an physical iPhone XR iOS 16.5.1 and am trying everything in both release and debug mode.

My appdelegate.swift (some values edited, function names edited but keep same format)

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds
import GoogleMaps
import workmanager

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ "testdeviceidhidden" ]
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("apikeyhidden")
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))
    WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "com.example.app-name.taskName1")
    WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "com.example.app-name.taskName2")
    WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "com.example.app-name.taskName3")

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

project.pbxproj

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    SystemCapabilities = {
        com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
            enabled = 1;
        };
    };
... rest of file below
```

info.plist

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.example.app-name.taskName1</string>
        <string>com.example.app-name.taskName2</string>
        <string>com.example.app-name.taskName3</string>
    </array>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>
```

Dart code for tasks is laid out like this for all tasks. They all are one-off tasks and have either a delay of zero, 5 seconds or up to one hour.

```
Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
        "taskName1", "taskName1",
        initialDelay: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        tag: "taskName1",
        inputData: {"inputData": inputData});
```

Dart code for receiving tasks in main.dart

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  var analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    if (task == "taskName1") {
      //Do some things and return result
    }
  }
}
```

For the most part I get the error
flutter: PlatformException(bgTaskSchedulingFailed(Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)") error, Scheduling the task using BGTaskScheduler has failed.

This implies that my set up is wrong, but I don't see where I have gone wrong.
I tried a solution where I changed my pubspec.yaml from including work manager: ^0.5.2 to this

```
workmanager:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/absar/flutter_workmanager.git
      ref: ios-bg-tasks-enh-final
```

This removed the error however the tasks were not running, even after leaving the application running on a physical device overnight. I did get this error in that case

[BackgroundTask] Background Task 27 ("task name"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.

As UIApplication.endBackgroundTask is swift (I believe) I have absolutely no clue how to call that through flutter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can see plenty of threads with people having issues running work manager on IOS (and just general background tasks, which I understand IOS doesn't make easy) but I'm seeing very few solutions, and none so far that work for me.